# Receber Informação de um Site

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, navegador-de-internet

Olá, pessoal!

Estou com um problema e já não sei mais o que fazer para resolver.
A situação é a seguinte: O meu programa acessa um site de venda de passagens aéreas... Ele precisa receber o primeiro valor da passagem, mas não faço ideia de como fazer isso.

Aqui um link de exemplo: http://www.decolar.com/shop/flights/results/oneway/GRU/ORL/2015-07-10/1/0/0

Bom, eu preciso pegar o primeiro valor que fica ali no quadrado amarelo.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me dar uma força ficarei muito grato!

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que você precisa é baixar a página. Isso não é difícil, então vou focar minha resposta na segunda parte.

Você precisa pegar esse elemento que você quer através do parser de DOM da biblioteca da linguagem que você tá usando. Para isso, vai ter que identificá-lo.

Usando o "Inspecionar elemento" do Firefox (botão direito na página -> Inspecionar elemento -> clique no quadradinho com uma seta que aparece no canto superior esquerdo do painel que aparece e passe o mouse em cima do elemento que você quer), eu consegui identificar que o elemento que você quer é da classe "amount price-amount". Através do `document.getElementsByClassName("amount price-amount")`, eu consegui 32 elementos como resposta. Logo, vi que teria que refinar a busca.

Usei a mesma ferramenta para procurar a(s) classe(s) do retângulo amarelo e vi que é "cluster cluster-ONEWAY default". Como queremos o primeiro, estamos atrás do elemento `document.getElementsByClassName("cluster cluster-ONEWAY default")[0]`. Basta então juntar as duas expressões: `document.getElementsByClassName("cluster cluster-ONEWAY default")[0].getElementsByClassName("amount price-amount")`. Isso nos retorna apenas dois `span`s. O primeiro é o preço em real e o segundo é o preço em dólar, que é o que você está procurando.

Note que, mesmo após a página estar carregada, esses dados ainda não apareceram. Portanto, você vai ter que executar esses comandos apenas após o carregamento da parte da página que você quer. Procure saber quais eventos a página lança após carregar essas partes e execute os comandos nesses eventos.

Comment: Olá Pablo, cara como vc conseguiu utilizar o comando document.getElementsByClassName ? O meu código dá erro dizendo que ele não faz parte da biblioteca...

Comment: Essa função não existe com esse nome no VB.net. Essa é a função Javascript que eu usei no console do navegador. Mas as bibliotecas padrão das linguagens costumam incluir algo assim. Pelo que eu vi, VB.net não tem, mas você pode usar essa solução aqui: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?536594-getElementsByClassName-Method
(avise se tiver problemas no inglês)

Comment: Não deu muito certo... Tentei fazer do jeito que você disse, mas ele não encontra nenhuma classe com o nome "amount price-amount"...
Tinha pensando anteriormente em receber as informações pelo código fonte da página, mas o valor não está lá... deve ser calculado na hora por alguma função ... N sei bem o que fazer mais